# In php how do I call function from another class inside a different class?

Tags: php, oop

how do I call function from another class inside a different class?

Here's my current code:

```
    <?php

    class database
    {
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $user = "root";
        private $password = "";
        private $db = "9dot";

        //connect to database
        public function connect()
        {
            $connect =  mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
            $database = mysql_select_db($this->db,$connect);

        }



        //Get exam headers
        public function GetExam()
        {
            $this->connect();
            $select = "SELECT e.ExamHeaderID, CONCAT(e.Firstname,' ',e.Lastname) AS Fullname e.Age, e.Position, e.Date FROM examheader e";
            $result = mysql_query($select);
            $table = "";
            $table .= "<th>ExamID</th>";
            $table .= "<th>Name</th>";
            $table .= "<th>Age</th>";
            $table .= "<th>Position</th>";
            $table .= "<th>Date</th>";

            $exam_id = "";
            $fullname = "";
            $age = "";
            $position = "";
            $date = "";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select))
            {
                $exam_id = mysql_real_escape_string($row['ExamHeaderID']);
                $fullname = mysql_real_escape_string($row['Fullname']);
                $age = mysql_real_escape_string($row['Age']);
                $position = mysql_real_escape_string($row['Position']);
                $date = mysql_real_escape_string($row['Date']);
            }

        }

        public function GetExamDetails($ExamID)
        {
            $this->connect();
            //$select = "SELECT ed.ExamDetailsID, ed.";
        }


        //Save Exam header
        public function SaveExam($firstname,$lastname, $age, $position)
        {
            $this->connect();
            $date = date("m/d/Y");
            mysql_real_escape_string($firstname);
            mysql_real_escape_string($lastname);
            mysql_real_escape_string($age);
            mysql_real_escape_string($position);
            $insert = "INSERT INTO examheader (Firstname,Lastname, Age, Position, Date) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$age','$position')";
            $result = mysql_query($insert);
            $exam_id = mysql_insert_id();
            //return exam id for insertion of exam details
            return $exam_id;

        }

        public function SaveExamAnswer()
        {


        }



    }

?>





<?php

include 'database.php';
$database = new $database();

class department
{
    $database->//property or function
}



?>
```

How do I call functions from database class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (rough example):

```
<?php

include 'database.php';


class department
{

    public function doSomething() {
       $database = new $database();
       $val = $database->GetExam();
       //do something
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can declare the instance of database in the department class like below :

```
class department
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $database = new database();
        $database->someFunction();
    }
}
```

If you don't wanna have it directly in your department class, you can declare it using the `global` system, assuming that the file needed is included, like below :

```
include 'database.php'

$database = new database();

class department
{
    public function __construct() 
    {
        global $database;
        $database->someFunction();
    }
}
```

See [PHP: Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Don't encourage people to use `global`!

Comment: I don't encourage him to use it, I just tell that it's also another way to do what he wants, even if it's not the rightest way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend them.

```
class department extends database {
    function test() {
        $this->getdbfunction();
    }
}
```

or you give them over the constructor:

```
class department {
    private $db;

    public function __construct(Database db) {
        $this->db = $db
    }
}

$department = new department($database);
```

Comment: Dependency injection method is the preferred method, in the opinion of the majority ;)

Comment: When you have a look at performance you should look and use the design patterns so this example is very simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can define an attribute wiche is an instance of the first class, and then applying methods to the defined attribute in the second class example :

```
class A {
function a () {
}
...
}

class B {
$attClassA;
function __construct(A objA) {
$this->attClassA = objA;
}
// you can use the attClassA in any class you want and then apply the chosen method
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an object of type 'database', then call the method using that:

```
$database = new database();
$connection = $database->connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this:**

If you don't want to include PHP files manually then use spl_autoload_register() function
else you need to include PHP file having class from which you want to import the method.

file-A.php - PHP file containing class A

```
<?php

class A{

   function DoSquare($x){
      return $x*$x;
    }

}

?>
```

---

file-B.php - PHP file containing class B

Assuming you are using spl_autoload_register():

```
<?php

class B{
   
   private $ObjectA = NULL;

   public function __construct(){
        $this->ObjectA = new A();
    }

   public function PrintSquare($x){
       echo $this->ObjectA->DoSquare($x);      
   }

}
?>
```

If manually including PHP file:

```
<?php

require("file-A.php");

class B{
   
   private $ObjectA = NULL;

   public function __construct(){
        $this->ObjectA = new A();
    }

   public function PrintSquare($x){
       echo $this->ObjectA->DoSquare($x);      
   }

}
?>
```